# IntelliSense for F# in Visual Studio 2012 Trial

Tags: f#, type-inference

I keep running into the following problem:

```
(System.Console.ReadLine ()).Split [|'('; ')'|]
|> Array.filter (fun s -> not (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty (s)))
|> Array.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|])
|> Array.map (fun s -> Array.map (fun t -> t.Trim ()) s) (* t.Trim () is underlined with a red squiggly line *)
|> [MORE CODE]
```

The error associated with the red squiggly line is:

`Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point.  A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object.  This may allow the lookup to be resolved.`

But when the mouse pointer hovers over `t`, IntelliSense correctly says that `t` is of `type string`.

I can bypass the error by writing `fun (t : string) -> [CODE]`, but I wonder why Visual Studio draws the squiggly line at all when it is already detecting the type of the variable correctly.  Is this a simple bug in the trial build, or am I misunderstanding something about F#'s type inferencing?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: seems that the compiler is not so clever as the intellisence :)

Comment: I've also seen this a few times in vs2010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some gap between F# intellisense and F# type checker.

The type checker works from left to right in order. Your problem can be fixed be changing:

```
fun s -> Array.map (fun t -> t.Trim()) s
```

to

```
fun s -> s |> Array.map (fun t -> t.Trim())
```

Since type of `s` is available before using `Array.map`, the type checker is able to infer type of `t`.

**Remarks:**

This error usually occurs when using instance methods. You could replace these methods by static functions with extra type annotation and refactor to make your code more composable:

```
let split arr (s: string) = s.Split arr
let trim (s: string) = s.Trim()

System.Console.ReadLine()
|> split [|'('; ')'|]
|> Array.filter (not << System.String.IsNullOrEmpty)
|> Array.map (split [|','|])
|> Array.map (Array.map trim)
```

Comment: also - you can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to avoid the `filter` step